# How to run a script when ever there is a new entry in database using SQLalchemy in python?

Tags: python, sql-server, database, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am new to SQL Alchemy and need a way to run a script whenever a new entry is added to a table. I am currently using the following method to get the task done but I am sure there has to be a more efficient way.

I am using python 2 for my project and MS SQL as database.

Suppose my table is carData and I add a new row for car details from website. The new car data is added to carData. My code works as follows

```
class CarData:
    <fields for table class>

with session_scope() as session:
    car_data = session.query(CarData)
    reference_df = pd.read_sql_query(car_data.statement, car_data.session.bind)

while True:
    with session_scope() as session:
        new_df = pd.read_sql_query(car_data.statement, car_data.session.bind)
        if len(new_df) > len(reference_df):
            print "New Car details added"
            <code to get the id of new row added>
            <run script>
            reference_df = new_df
    sleep(10)
```

The above is ofcourse a much simpler version of the code that I am using but the idea is to have a reference point then keep checking every 10 seconds if there is a new entry. However even after using session_scope() I have seen connection issues after a few days as this script is suppose to run indefinitely.

Is there a better way to know that a new row has been added, get the id of the new row and run the required script?

Comment: Please stop using Python 2!

Comment: What problems are you having "after a few days"? It looks like you're appending data to a dataframe continually, so there's a chance you're hitting a memory issue. We need a bit more context around the problem you're having (e.g. exceptions) and perhaps an idea around what you're wanting to do with the new rows?

Comment: Thank you @gvee for the comment. It's unlikely that it will hit memory issue because the new entry comes like once in a couple of days. I get "OperationalError:  TCP Provider: Error code 0x68".
Also this seems to be a lot of manual checking, is there any module or method in sqlalchemy that can do the task better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error you've described is a connectivity issue with the database e.g. a temporary network problem

> OperationalError: TCP Provider: Error code 0x68

So what you need to do is cater this with error handling!

```py
try:
    new_df = pd.read_sql_query(car_data.statement, car_data.session.bind)
except:
    print("Problem with query, will try again shortly")
```

Comment: I will give this a try.